# migrating to dbcontext LINQ where clause string parameter

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, dbcontext

I'm migrating my project from ObjectContext to DbContext and I have a problem with this sentence:

```
var query = db.Inventory.Where("it.IdState in {" + states + "}");
```

This works with ObjectContext but now I get an error at compilation time:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Test.DAL.Inventory, bool>>'
```

Seems not to be posible to do this now, I tryied to expose ObjectContext to do it, but I couldn't find the way

Any idea?
Thank!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can (and should) strongly type these arguments as an expression.

```
var query = db.Inventory.Where(x => states.Contains(x.IdState));
```

Answer (score 3):

You kind of need to reverse it

```
var query = db.Inventory.Where(it => states.Contains(it.IdState));
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.Where` method syntax can't be used in the manner you have. In order that please use the following

```
var q = db.Inventory.Where(i => states.Contains(i.IdState));
```

Check the example below on 'fruit' in order to understand better how the `.Where` clause is used

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx

**Resources:**

[Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The argument of `Where` must be a delegate which formulates a condition. Replace

```
"it.IdState in {" + states + "}"
```

with

```
it => states.Contains(it.IdState)
```

to solve the problem using a lambda expression.